# Export and import a table without a specific column

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export, auto-increment

I'm trying to export a table with an Auto Increment `rowid` column and then import it in another server.

Considering that the column is primary key and can't accept duplicate keys if i import rows after backup from old server, new rows with same `rowid` would be added to new server.

i also don't want to change start number for Auto Increment in new server and cause gaps in rows.

so i thought one solution can be exporting new rows without `rowid` and letting new server to assign new `rowid` to them. but how can i do that directly with mysql or with help with phpMyAdmin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is to use [LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), but override the columns list so the auto-increment value is inserted into a dummy variable:

Here's a demo:

I have a text file I call `c.csv`:

```
1       foo     bar
2       baz     bam
3       blee    bloo
```

I want to insert into mytable, but id's 1,2,3 are already occupied. I want the csv data to be inserted, but given new id's.

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | text | text |
|  2 | text | text |
|  3 | text | text |
+----+------+------+
```

Here's a solution:

```
mysql> load data local infile 'c.csv' into table mytable (@dummy, col1, col2);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | text | text |
|  2 | text | text |
|  3 | text | text |
|  4 | foo  | bar  |
|  5 | baz  | bam  |
|  6 | blee | bloo |
+----+------+------+
```

It added the three rows from my csv file, but the `id` column on each row of input was detoured into the dummy variable, so the rows had to use the default, allocating new auto-increment id's.

P.S.: You need to let go of your desire to have no gaps in the sequence if id's. Gaps are normal. You may delete some rows in the future. You may attempt an insert but it gets rolled back or gets an error. There are also cases where InnoDB generates non-consecutive id values by design (read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html for details).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.
i'm ok with some gaps but didn't want to have a big gap

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty way to accomplish the task:

1. Create a new table on the old server using the same schema *minus* the primary key
2. Copy the records from the source table to the dummy table
3. Export the data using `mysqldump` or something in phpMyAdmin
4. Change the `INSERT INTO {table}` strings in the export to have the correct table name
5. Import the data to the new server

There are likely other ways, such as a temporary before `TRIGGER` that will replace the `id` with NULL so that the auto-increment continues, but the above method would likely be the fastest ...

Answer (score 2):

As you insert, add a big number (big enough to be past the existing ids) to the `id` column for the incoming rows.

Plan A:  Load into a temp table, then `INSERT .. SELECT id+100000, ... FROM temp`.

Plan B:

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE ...
        ..., @id = id, ...
        SET id = @id + 100000
```

Caveat:  You must not be inserting into the table from other sources during the load; it could create an id that will conflict.